# added a new domain to the same ip, new domain rendering first domains wordpress blog?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, wordpress

i am running a ec2 instance, and I had a wordpress blog on that server for domain#1.

Today I pointed domain#2, setup the directory and nginx etc.

Going to www.domain#2.com I am seeing the content for domain#1.

What do I have to do so each domain is mapped correctly?  I thought that was what the nginx file was for that I created for each domain?

Comment: How did you add domain#2 to the nginx config?

Comment: not to the config sorry, but to the available-sites and enabled-sites symbolic link.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Hosts are your friend.

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxVirtualHostExample

Comment: i did this, except I have 2 files that, one for each domain in my available-sites.

Comment: are the files actually included into the running configuration? what happens when you paste them into the main config as one file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the domain#2 top of the domain#1 in your config